# How to add chrome and chrome headless browsers in the script section of .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, continuous-integration

I am writing browser rspec test for rails and it works fine locally because chrome is installed on my system.

I would like to put installation of chrome and headless chrome in the script field of the ".gitlab-ci.yml" 
So how could I proceed here to write CI file which install chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 common options that came to mind:

1. Create your own docker image (via `Dockerfile`) that you're going to use in GitLab CI and just install Chrome Headless there
2. Add [`selenium/standalone-chrome`](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/) as a `service` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` and configure Capybara (or whatever you're using for testing) to access selenium remotely. There is [a fine article](https://dev.to/zimski/the-complete-guide-to-setup-a-cicd-for-rails-5-on-gitlab-2f2d) I found with detailed instructions of how to set it all up

Comment: Thanks GProst. I have tried second approach with reference of article but still facing the issue.  after executing CI getting the same problem of                       
error ArgumentError: wrong first argument

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Probably would be better if you opened a separate question with your specific issue

Comment: Are there any recommended documents that cover the first option? Allowing me to create my own image and using this in the pipeline